# What does "Assistant handler on the device" mean in google play permissions policy?

Tags: java, android, permissions, sms

My Android app uses SMS send and SMS receive permission, but i am unable to publish it on to the pay store because of the new Permissions Policies(My app is getting rejected)

"It must be actively registered as the default SMS or Assistant handler on the device."

Can anyone explain what is "**Assistant handler on the device**"?

Source: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/

By the way, Truecaller uses both call and sms permission though they are not the default phone and sms handler in my phone?

Comment: Hi, you found any solution on this?

Comment: Google not explain anything about Default Assistant Handler in the documentation